# how to write vba code for selecting rows from a sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner in vba...i am doing a task which consist of 6 sequences..

Sequence 1

Sequence 2

Sequence 3

Sequence 4

Sequence 5

Sequence 6

In sheet-1 i have done all the calculations for all 6 sequences and tabulated the results..
The order of sequence changes according to constraints...i.e, "1,2,3","1,2,4","1,3,4","1,3,5"..)...

Is it possible to pick the required sequence along with its contents(tabulated results) from sheet-1 and display it in another sheet?

(i.e., For sequence order "1,2,4",only sequences 1,2 and 4 from sheet 1 should be displayed in another sheet)

Kindly help me to solve my problem..

I would like to add more data..

In *Sheet 1* i have created a table which gives the order of sequence to be followed

**Input data**

Enter A

Enter B

Enter C (True or False)

**Constraints**

If (AND(A=B,C="TRUE"),"1,2,3",IF(AND(A<>B,C="TRUE"),"1,2,4",IF(AND(A=B,C="FALSE"),"1,3,4",IF(AND((A<>B,C="FALSE"),"1,3,5",""))))

**RESULT DISPLAYED**

1,2,3  OR   1,2,4   OR  1,3,4    OR   1,3,5  (DEPENDING ON MY INPUT DATA)

IN *SHEET 2* I HAVE DONE THE CALCULATIONS FOR ALL THE SIX SEQUENCES

**SEQUENCE 1**

A) VERIFICATION OF X

B) VERIFICATION OF Y

C) VERIFICATION OF Z

**SEQUENCE 2**

A) VERIFICATION OF P

B) VERIFICATION OF Q

C) VERIFICATION OF R

**. 
.
.
.**

TILL **SEQUENCE 6**

NOW, i want to filter my sequence according to the result displayed in sheet 1

example: If the sequence displayed in sheet 1 is 1,3,4 either only these sequences should be displayed in sheet 2 or the sequences 1,3,4 selected from sheet 2 shuold be displayed in sheet 3...

Comment: You could use a sheet or checkboxes that relate to each sequence.  Then if the box is checked or a cell is true, do that sequence.  Each of your sequences would need to do a check for T or F for that control or use a cell like A1 for sequence 1 and just give it a drop down of true or false.

Comment: @TKEyi60: Thank you for the response..Kindly find the data added to the question...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that each sequence is a formula that produces a number (if not, post some sample data). Also assuming that the number is the order you want things displayed. Assuming sample data like this in Range("A1:A4):

```
=D1+D2
=D3+D4
=E4+E4
=F4+F5
```

Values like this in Range("A1:A4"):

```
5
4
1
2
```

So the order you want is A3, A4, A2, A1. Here is the VBA code:

```
'Copy the data so that we can maintain the original (optional)
For i = 1 to 4
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Offset(i-1,0).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(i-1,0).Value
next i

'Sort the new data
ActiveSheet.Columns("B").Sort key1:=Range("B1"), _
      order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlNo

'Copy the new sorted rows to another worksheet
For i = 1 to 4
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i-1,0).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Offset(i-1,0).Value
next i
```

I made a lot of assumptions, so not sure if I got it right. Posting sample data makes it easier to answer.

Comment: I am still confused. Is "Enter A" the data in Cell A1 of Sheet 1? Or is it some numeric value? "A) VERIFICATION OF X". What is "A"? What is "X"?